# Represent short form of IPV6 Address

Tags: java, methods, ipv6, utility

I have an IPv6 address string: 2001:1:0:0:10:0:10:10

I want to represent it as a short form of IPV6 string: 2001:1::10:0:10:10

Does any one know the java methods to do this?

Comment: Tip: "It's very urgent" isn't going to win you any favours around here

Comment: I'll go get coffee, Google the answer and think about posting the solution. Give me 4 hours. :p

Comment: There's a great Java-specific answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043983/ipv6-address-into-compressed-form-in-java/7044170#7044170

Answer (score 0):

Since it can be shorten in many different ways in some cases, there is probably no such function in java API. You can manually do:

```
Inet6Address.getByName("1080::8:800:200C:417A").replaceFirst("(:0)+:", "::");
```

but I did'n test it very well. There might be some cases this code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can provides numerous ways of producing strings for IPv4 and/or IPv6, including the canonical string for IPv6 matching rfc 5952.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

The method toCanonicalString() produces the canonical string, there is also a method toCompressedString() that is slightly different.  With the canonical string a single segment of zero is not compressed, but toCompressedString() will compress such a segment.  The method toNormalizedString() will not compress at all.

Using your example 2001:1:0:0:10:0:10:10 and another here is sample code:

```java
IPAddress addr = new IPAddressString("2001:1:0:0:10:0:10:10").getAddress();
System.out.println(addr.toNormalizedString());
System.out.println(addr.toCanonicalString());
System.out.println(addr.toCompressedString());
System.out.println();

addr = new IPAddressString("2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1").getAddress();
System.out.println(addr.toNormalizedString());
System.out.println(addr.toCanonicalString());
System.out.println(addr.toCompressedString());
```

Output:

```
2001:1:0:0:10:0:10:10
2001:1::10:0:10:10
2001:1::10:0:10:10

2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1
2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1
2001:db8::1:1:1:1:1
```